# How to group/order parameterised tests in a pytest class

Tags: python, pytest

I have this test class:

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize(["arg"], [["one"], ["two"]])
class TestFoo:
    def test_a(self, arg):
        print("a", arg)

    def test_b(self, arg):
        print("b", arg)
```

I'm getting this output:

```
a one
a two
b one
b two
```

What can I do to get this output?

```
a one
b one
a two
b two
```

I want all tests for the first parameter to execute first, and only then all tests for the second parameter.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I needed [scenario support](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/parametrize.html#a-quick-port-of-testscenarios):

```py
def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    idlist = []
    argvalues = []
    if hasattr(metafunc.cls, "scenarios"):
        for scenario in metafunc.cls.scenarios:
            idlist.append(scenario[0])
            items = scenario[1].items()
            argnames = [x[0] for x in items]
            argvalues.append([x[1] for x in items])
        metafunc.parametrize(argnames, argvalues, ids=idlist, scope="class")

scenario1 = ("scenario1": {"arg": "one"})
scenario2 = ("scenario2": {"arg": "one"})

class TestFoo:
    scenarios = [scenario1, scenario2]

    def test_a(self, arg):
        print("a", arg)

    def test_b(self, arg):
        print("b", arg)
```

Then the output is what I expect.